# Java MulticastSocket with datagram source defined

Tags: java, sockets, networking, nio, multicast

I am trying to subscribe to a particular market data feed, distributed by multicast via FAST protocol. In Java, there is `MulticastSocket` and there is `DatagramChannel` supporting multicast.

The FAST protocol library I use, OpenFAST, accepts `MulticastSocket` instances to create endpoints, but it seems to be impossible to specify source IP address in its configuration, it binds to "any source", which doesn't work with this market data feed. It *is* possible (since Java 1.7) to create a `DatagramChannel` with source IP defined, like described here:

```java
NetworkInterface interf = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("225.0.0.100");
InetAddress source = InetAddress.getByName("172.20.40.1");

DatagramChannel dc = DatagramChannel.open(ProtocolFamily.INET)
    .setOption(SocketOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
    .bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000))
    .setOption(SocketOption.IP_MULTICAST_IF, interf);

MembershipKey key = dc.join(group, interf, source); // <- source specified
```

However, I don't see a way to get a `MulticastSocket` from channel, the `socket()` method returns just the plain old `DatagramSocket`.

Is there a way to create a `MulticastSocket` with source filtering enabled, either directly or from `DatagramChannel`?

Answer (score 2):

[`java.nio.MulticastChannel`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/nio/channels/MulticastChannel.html) implements source-specific multicast, which is only available in IGMPv3. [`java.net.MulticastSocket`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html), on the other hand, only supports IGMPv2, so you are out of luck here.

I would suggest you filter unneeded multicast sources out at the firewall level, but you can also try [`DatagramSocket.connect()`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#connect%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29) to establish source filtering in the app.

Hope this helps.